# How to check for installed package in Puppet?

Tags: puppet, rpm

I'm downloading a RPM using wget and I want to check if the package is installed before I download it. I'm not using a RPM repo, so I can't just do

```
package { ...
  ensure => installed
}
```

How can I do something like:

```
if HOW_TO_CHECK_IF_PACKAGE_X_IS_INSTALLED
   ... do wget etc.
```

Before someone asks, this didn't work for me: [Puppet - test if a package already defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266347/puppet-test-if-a-package-already-defined)

Comment: I used custom facters before to check e.g. if a file exists so I've got the feeling I need  custom facter for this one too I just don't know how to write it

Comment: Yes, but nitpick: Those are called *facts*. The tool itself is named *Facter* but each item is referred to as a *fact*.

Answer (score 3):

If you're downloading an RPM and installing it, you could do so like this:

```
package { 'foo':
  ensure   => installed,
  provider => 'rpm',
  source   => 'http://example.com/foo.rpm',
}
```

Comment: I figured it out in the end, I needed a custom facter:

Comment: Ok, I'm just curious: whats the benefit to using a custom fact when this would do the exact same outcome without the additional work of calling out to facter?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a custom facter:

```
require"puppet"
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:package_installed, :type => :rvalue) do |args|
    packageName = args[0]
    return system "rpm --quiet -q #{packageName}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Dude this is **not** a custom fact. It's a parser function that is run *on the master* and queries packages that are installed *on the master machine*. If you are using `puppet apply` this just happens to work, but is not a solution really.

Comment: Indeed, if you want a fact to get the package installation status, you should do something like the edit I just made